# How to remove a particular item from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My Dom is like this :

```html
<div class="child">
  child1
  <button class="btn">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="child">
  child2
  <button class="btn">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="child">
  child3
  <button class="btn">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="child">
  child4
  <button class="btn">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Now my js like this:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btn.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
    boxes.splice(i, 1);
  });
});
```

Now boxes is an array and after clicking on delete button I want to remove The pertucal item from that arrray. but it throws the following error:

```
boxes.splice() is not a function
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `splice()` at all here? This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is an array method. The collection returned from `querySelectorAll()` is Array-like. Use something like `...` spread operator to convert it to an array.

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btn.forEach((button, i)=>{
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.child')];
        boxes.splice(i, 1)
    })
})
```

Note: This doesn't actually delete anything from the DOM. Only removes it from the array as you have indicated in the question.

Comment: It works. I'm gonna accept it. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

The **querySelectorAll** returns a noed list You have to convert it to an array

```
const nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const nodelistToArray = Array.apply(null, nodelist);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now boxes is an array and ...

Actually, `boxes` is NOT an array, as you think. `boxes` is the result of `document.querySelectorAll`, which returns a `NodeList`, not an array. A `NodeList` is very similar to an array, but it doesn't have all of the methods of `Array.prototype`. To use `.splice` on a `NodeList`, you have to convert it to an array. Here is how you would do that:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btn.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.child'));
    console.log(boxes.splice(i, 1));
  });
});
```